# How to make this part of my layout work?

Tags: html

How can I make this part of my layout work?

I can't work out how to fix this. Its become so messy and confusing.

```
    <div style='width: 900px; margin:0 auto'><div style='float: left; width: 312px; height: 197px; background-color: #A857BC'></div>
    <div style='float: left; width: 249px; height: 197px; background-color: #FF80C0'></div>
    <div style='float: left; width: 339px; height: 197px; background-color: #8C83FC'></div>
    </div><div style='margin:50px;background-color: #99CCCC; margin-top:-150px;height:100px; '>this should be in the middle</div>

</div>

    <div style='width: 900px; margin:0 auto'><div style='float: left; width: 362px; height: 197px; background-color: #A857BC'></div>
    <div style='float: left; width: 147px; height: 197px; background-color: #FF80C0'></div>
    <div style='float: left; width: 391px; height: 197px; background-color: #8C83FC'></div>
    </div><div style='margin:50px;background-color: #99CCCC; margin-top:-150px;height:100px; '>this should be in the middle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem with it? What would you like to accomplish?

Comment: What do you want it to do? You have two closing divs too many. Don't use inline css cause you won't be able to see what the #$&* happens this way :)

Comment: On an unrelated note, you might also want to try using external css...

Comment: @jack it IS css. It's just inline.

Comment: let me introduce you to id attribute and external css. Try to minimize your inline css... And I am pretty sure your problem have to do with the fact that you don't actually nest your divs, which means, well just mess. You should have your main div wrapper starting at the top and different parts of the page within it... `<div id="wrap"><div id="sidebar"></div><div id="content"></div></div>`

Comment: @PeeHaa, right that's what I meant. Indentation is good too.

Answer (score 1):

You have some stray closing `</div>` tags in there, make sure they are in balanced pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat, you're going to want to include an external style sheet. This will make your life much easier. See my example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/kSxrK/2/

Can you please explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish. I see the text doesn't appear - but where do you want it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style='width: 900px; margin:0 auto'>
  <div style='float: left; width: 312px; height: 197px; background-color: #A857BC'></div>
  <div style='float: left; width: 249px; height: 197px; background-color: #FF80C0'></div>
  <div style='float: left; width: 339px; height: 197px; background-color: #8C83FC'></div>
</div>
<div style='margin:50px;background-color: #99CCCC; margin-top:-150px;height:100px; '>this should be in the middle</div>

<div style='width: 900px; margin:0 auto'>
  <div style='float: left; width: 362px; height: 197px; background-color: #A857BC'></div>
  <div style='float: left; width: 147px; height: 197px; background-color: #FF80C0'></div>
  <div style='float: left; width: 391px; height: 197px; background-color: #8C83FC'></div>
</div>
<div style='margin:50px;background-color: #99CCCC; margin-top:-150px;height:100px; '>this should be in the middle</div>
```

or

```
<div style='width: 900px; margin:0 auto'>
  <div style='float: left; width: 312px; height: 197px; background-color: #A857BC'></div>
  <div style='float: left; width: 249px; height: 197px; background-color: #FF80C0'></div>
  <div style='float: left; width: 339px; height: 197px; background-color: #8C83FC'></div>
  <div style='margin:50px;background-color: #99CCCC; margin-top:-150px;height:100px; '>this should be in the middle</div>
</div>

<div style='width: 900px; margin:0 auto'>
  <div style='float: left; width: 362px; height: 197px; background-color: #A857BC'>        </div>
  <div style='float: left; width: 147px; height: 197px; background-color: #FF80C0'></div>
  <div style='float: left; width: 391px; height: 197px; background-color: #8C83FC'></div>
  <div style='margin:50px;background-color: #99CCCC; margin-top:-150px;height:100px; '>this should be in the middle</div>
</div>
```

depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

That code is *ridiculously messy* - extra closing tags, inline styles, duplicated styles, inconsistent indentation. Also, you're using single quotes - while there's nothing wrong with that, double quotes are more common.  You should have included a picture in your question.

This is my best guess as to what you were trying to go for.

```
<div style="width:900px; margin:0 auto; position:relative; height:197px">
    <div style="float:left; width:312px; height:100%; background-color:#a857bc"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:249px; height:100%; background-color:#ff80c0"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:339px; height:100%; background-color:#8c83fc"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #9cc; position:absolute; top:50px; bottom:50px; left:50px; right:50px">this should be in the middle</div>
</div>
<div style="width:900px; margin:0 auto; position:relative; height:197px">
    <div style="float:left; width:362px; height:100%; background-color:#a857bc"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:147px; height:100%; background-color:#ff80c0"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:391px; height:100%; background-color:#8c83fc"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #9cc; position:absolute; top:50px; bottom:50px; left:50px; right:50px">this should be in the middle</div>
</div>
```

You should listen to the other answers/comments regarding the use of inline styles.